# Librería para dibujar y=f(x) desde node js directamente

Tags: nodejs, plot

Estoy usando una librería llamada nodeplotlib, muy simple de usar pero está muy poco desarrollada y no me permite dibujar dos curvas superpuestas o resaltar puntos de una curva
[image: resultado de usar nodeplotlib]
Desearía saber si existe algo mejor, que también lo pueda llamar directamente desde node js.

Comment: Mira [Cómo crear gráficas usando node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15477008/how-to-create-charts-using-nodejs): recomiendan: google chart, chart js, chartlis,d3, highcharts, gnuplot... Lo mejor sería que buscaras en la documentación un ejemplo con el template que deseas. No me queda claro si quieres con leyendas, con ejes de escala distinta, una gráfica interactiva o estática.

Comment: Por lo que veo nodeplotlib está construida sobre plotly js la cual es muy completa y sí permite poner dos gráficas super puestas: mira la [documentación](https://plotly.com/javascript/line-charts/) puedes activar/desactivar las gráficas dandole click a las leyendas